# How to unmerge the excel fields while exporting from crystal reports 9.2

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I am exporting crystal report to excel file using vb6.0.

When i tried to export the crystal report file to excel the columns are merged.I need to unmerge all the fields so that i can manipulate data in excel sheet.

Comment: i solved myself with the below code 
worksheet.rows.select
selection.unmerge in vb

Comment: Sounds like a useful bit of information. Go ahead and post that as an answer, and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for each ws in workbook
ws.activate
ws.rows.entirerow.select
selection.unmerge
ws.cells(2,1).select
next
```